# How exclude certain appsettings files from publishing

Tags: msbuild, web-deployment, asp.net-core-2.0, web-deployment-project, coreclr

I have asp.net core 2 application. Based on [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/?view=aspnetcore-2.0&tabs=aspnetcore2x#deploy-the-app) i have created `.pubxml` file for my development environment. I am using web deployment (remote agent) to deploy the web package to target web server.  On our build server where, jenkins is installed, i run the following command to build & deploy

```
D:\Jenkins\myproject\workspace\myapplication\Src\Api>dotnet publish Api.csproj /p:PublishProfile=development.pubxml
```

It builds and deploys the application successfully to target web server.

However my application has multiple `appsettings` files specific to each environment. For example `appsettings.json`, `appsettings.development.json`, `appsettings.staging.json` and `appsettings.production.json` The deployment process deploys all the appsettings files to web server. (in this case to development web server)

How do i only include environment specific appsettings file? (in this case i want to deploy `appsettings.json`, `appsettings.development.json` but not other 2 files)

Answer (score 38):

You can add `<ItemGroup>` definitions to your publish profiles (.pubxml files) containing update statements for the files.

For example if the publish profile is named `Production.pubxml`/ `Staging.pubxml` according to the environment, you can add this item group to the root `<Project>` xml node:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <Content Update="appsettings.*.json" CopyToPublishDirectory="Never" />
  <Content Update="appsettings.$(MSBuildThisFileName).json" CopyToPublishDirectory="PreserveNewest" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Comment: Worked for me. I just added   <Content Update="appsettings.json" CopyToPublishDirectory="Never" /> to ignore the non-specific environment file.

Answer (score 8):

I could handle this with the following `*.pubxml`:

```xml
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
   .
   .
   .
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Update="appsettings.Development.json">
      <CopyToPublishDirectory>Never</CopyToPublishDirectory>
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Never</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </Content>
    <Content Update="appsettings.TestBed.json">
      <CopyToPublishDirectory>Never</CopyToPublishDirectory>
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Never</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </Content>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Comment: is this going to work on csproj file?

Comment: No, it is publish file with `pubxml` extension

Comment: thats disappointing. but thanks for the info there

Comment: Worked for me adding the `<CopyToPublishDirectory>Never</CopyToPublishDirectory>` to the csproj file. No more appsettings files when using "Publish". Thanks!